# Error: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1905; index=-1

Tags: android-studio, webservice, substring, jsonarray

Estoy recibiendo un JSONArray, y me esta dando este error cuando intento usar esta linea de código:

> substr = cadena.substring(cadena.indexOf("https"));

El error completo es este:

```
Process: com.seccion.seccin15hibrida, PID: 4755
    java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1905; index=-1
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1893)
        at com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.Inicio$1.onResponse(Inicio.java:117)
        at com.seccion.seccin15hibrida.Inicio$1.onResponse(Inicio.java:96)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Mi linea 117 es esta:

> substr = cadena.substring(cadena.indexOf("https"));

Mi bloque de código completo donde me esta dando el error es este:

```
    if(cadena != null){
       try{
           substr = cadena.substring(cadena.indexOf("https"));
           String[] parts = substr.split(".pdf");
           String parte = parts[0];
           Log.i("hope","Valor: "+parte);
           substrimg = cadena.substring(cadena.indexOf("https"));
           String[] partsImg = substrimg.split(".png");
           String parte2 = partsImg[0];
           Log.i("hopeImg","Valor: "+parte2);
           linkImgajustado = parte2 + ".png";
           if (parte2.endsWith("png") || parte2.endsWith(".jpg") ||   parte2.endsWith("jpeg")){
   }else{
         parte = parte+".pdf";
         linkajustado = parte;
         Log.i("link","Valor: "+parte);
         }
   }catch (Error error){
         Log.i("errorPDF","Error: "+error);
                       }
   }else{
         Log.i("ErrorN","Se recibio un valor vacio en el adaptador de noticias");
   }
```

No entiendo como puedo corregir el error, por lo que entiendo en el 
**StringIndexOutOfBoundsException** es un error con el texto que estoy pasando por mi sub string pero no se como resolverlo

Comment: El problema es que en la cadena no te encuentra la palabra "https" entonces el indexOf es -1 y a partir de ahí no te funciona el código.

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia tienes razón, muchas gracias, ya aplique una validacion para evitar que eso pase, puedes poner tu comentario como respuesta para poder marcarla como respuesta?

Comment: Tranquilo, aquí el objetivo es ayudar. No sólo ganar puntos.